# Quisiera cambiar el formato en el que se me presenta el tiempo de "segundos" a "HH/MM/SS"

Tags: python

Tengo un dato que viene en este formato de tiempo "0000:30" que significa que ese video dura 30s. Lo tengo que transformar para que venga en un formato "HH/mm/ss".

Quiero automatizar este proceso y que si en un futuro me llega un video de 200s me salga el dato como "00:03:20"

Gracias de antemano :)

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
string='1525:05'
resultado = dt.strptime(string, '%H%M:%S').time()
print(resultado)
```

Suponemos que tu video dura 15horas, 25minutos y  5segundos entrado el valor tal y como dices que te llega ("0000:30")

Salida / Output :

```
15:25:05
```

Comment: Nota : si en `dt.strptime(string, '%H%M:%S').time()` no utilizas `.time()` al final, la salida que te generara te devolvera también una fecha. Utilizando .time() solo obtienes el tiempo que es lo que quieres.